# access report or subquery separate by project

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I just have a quick question about generating reports based different projects or names. 
Currently, I have a form which allows `start date`, `end date`, `project`, and `name` to be selected.
The selected values are used for some parameter queries and reports.

If i were to leave my project and name inputs blank. Then my query would show
active projects `A, B, C, D` and etc between the start date and end date. In addition, the names of people working on the projects would also be shown.

In my report, I would like a breakdown by `Project` and then by the `Name` of people working on that project.

Is something like that possible without inputting project and names?

Thank you very much,

Francis

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: i tried running another query finding unique projects from the first query. then a subquery based on the unique projects. then i was thinking another layer finding unique names for a project. kind of like nested for loops except its nested queries. does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a report and open it in `Design View` you should see `Grouping & Totals` in the ribbon at the top.

Once you click on that, a menu at the bottom of your report will open. If you group on `Project` and sort by `Name` I believe you will get your desired results.

Comment: sorry but the end goal is to calculate sum and average based on person and project between the start and end date for all project and people. unfortunately group and sort won't work

Comment: Couldn't you create a report footer that would sum the cost of each person/project and divide by the number of records to get the average?